# AWS DynamoDb could not unconvert attribute error for nested Maps

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a class I use to do CRUD operations on a Dynamo table. One of its attributes is a `Map<String,Object>` since it needs to support both types of `Map<String,String>` as well as `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` and `Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,String>>>`

```
@DynamoDBDocument
@Getters
@Setters
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {

     @DynamoDBAttribute
     @DynamoDBHashKey
     private String id;

     @DynamoDBAttribute
     @DynamoDBRangeKey
     private String type;

     @DynamoDBAttribute
     private String subType;


     @DynamoDBAttribute
     private Map<String, Object> payload;

     public void setPayload(Map<String, String> payload){
     Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
     payload.forEach(map::put);
     this.payload = map;
   }
}
```

This works well with writing to the DB, it successfully takes both types with no issues. The problem I'm having is when I try to query the table to get a list matching a specific `type`. I get the error saying `Foo<payload> could not unconvert attribute`. Here's how I do the querying :

```
public List<Foo> getFooList (String type){
DynamoDBQueryExpression query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression();
query.withRangeKeyCondition("type",
                    new Condition()
                            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(type)));
        }
List<Foo> Foos = getMapper().query(Foo.class, query);
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You also need to give a hash-key when querying